# Generate “item tag” pairs from “item,item,...|tag” lists

Tags: sed, grep

The characteristics of the input data:

- Each line consists of two fields, separated by a pipe '|', where
- the first field is a comma-separated list of items, and
- the second field is a tag.

Input

```
100,210,354,462|acct
331,746,50|mis
90,263,47,14|sales
```

Output

```
100acct
210acct
354acct
462acct
331mis
746mis
50mis
90sales
263sales
47sales
14sales
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the items contain no “|” and the tags contain no “,”:

```
awk -F '[,|]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)print$i$NF}' input.txt
```

Comment: Nice! I did not know you could give multiple field separators to gawk.

Comment: @terdon you can use any (awk-compatible) regular expression for the separator.

Answer (score 1):

Will PERL do?

```
$ perl -ne 'chomp; @a=split(/\|/); @b=split(/,/,$a[0]); map{print "$_$a[1]\n"}@b' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

And now, in bash and sed only:

```
cat test.txt| while IFS="|" read i t ; do echo $i | sed "s/\([0-9]\+\)/\1$t/g;s/,/\n/g" ; done
```

And in bash only (courtesy Nahuel Fouilleul):

```
 while IFS="|" read i t;do while read -d, j;do echo "$j$t";done <<<"$i,";done <test.txt
```

Comment: Still not `bash` only due to the UUOC (Useless Use of `cat`).

Comment: `$t` and `\1` should be swapped in `sed`.

Comment: full bash version : `while IFS="|" read i t;do while read -d, j;do echo "$j$t";done <<<"$i,";done <test.txt`, may be more efficient on small files but for larger files awk will be a better choice

Answer (score 1):

Pure sed solution:

```
sed ':a;s/\(.*\),\([^,]*\)|\(.*\)/\2\3\n\1|\3/;ta;s/|//' input.file
```

Answer (score -1):

Sed...

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\),.*|\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

if the first field isn't numeric, then  it can be changed to something like

```
sed -e 's/^\([^,][^,]*\),.*|\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

Comment: This will only produce the first item-tag pair.

Comment: Oh yes - I missed that part of it!